# Insert timestamp in the next cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have prepared above script if I change the column 51 cell value 0 to 1 then date need to captured in the next cell in column 52

```
function onEdit() {
  var s= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Audit Sheet_May" ) { var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() == 51)
  Var nextCell= r.offset(0, 1);
  if( nextCell.getValue()=== '') nextCell.setValue(new Date()); 
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 51 || e.range.getSheet().getName() !== 'Audit Sheet_May') {
    return;
  }
  const nextCell = e.range.offset(0, 1, 1, 1);
  if (!nextCell.getValue()) {
    nextCell
      .setValue(new Date())
      .setNumberFormat('M/d/yyyy');
  }
}
```

See these [onEdit(e) optimization tips](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).

If you need to run this function on several sheets or several columns, use a more flexible script, such as [yetAnotherTimestamp_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135269995?msgid=135276870).